# Socket clips Data, Lighttpd, PHP <-> C

Tags: php, sockets, network-programming, lighttpd

I'm using Lighttpd with fcgi to execute a PHP Script.

This Script opens a Socket, sends the query string to this Socket and the Socket response is printed via `echo $buffer;`

This works very well until a certain response data size.

At approx. 3kb of Data the response is cut.

I have already tried to increase the `len` param in `socket_recv` without success.

On the other side of the Socket is a C Application which sends the complete data. I have checked this with an console and "nc"

This is my PHP-Script:

```
// socket_create ...
// socket_connect ...
// socket_send ...

//Now receive reply from server
if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf , 10000 , 0 ) === FALSE)
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}
echo $buf;
```

If I set the MSG_WAITALL Flag within `socket_recv()`  I get the complete response but only after a Timeout, so this could not be a solution but it shows the my C Application prints all the Data to the Socket.

I'm using Linux as OS. 
Any suggestions? How could I increase the socket size?
What could be the reason that I don't get the complete data from the Socket?

Comment: You've got to keep calling `recv()`.

Comment: Ok, with an 2nd call of recv() I'm getting the rest of my Data.
Trying now to catch all data with a while-loop. Thank you.